# User Profiles When Migrating From Stand Alone Server To Domain Controller

Tags: windows

The Administrator profile on a stand alone (non DC) windows server is a local account.  (pls correct me if I'm wrong)

So What happens to the (local) Administrator profile when a stand alone server is migrated to a domain controller and that DC is the PDC  (A new DC in a new domain - call it DomainX)

- A) Does windows take that profile and then convert it to an AD integrated (domain) profile?  (convert meaning use that one, not create a new one and replace it)
- B  ) If so, what happens when another stand alone server is migrated (as another DC in DomainX) also? (assume it becomes the BDC for DomainX)  I'm asking since there would be another local account called 'Administrator' and there cannot be two accounts named 'Adminitrator' with different SIDs, correct?  So exactly what exactly happens to it?  Does windows then also convert/integrate that local 'Administrator' account (on the machine that will become the BDC) to the existing 'Administrator' domain acount?  Or is it just abandoned and a new 'Administrator' account (I mean the DomainX 'Administrator' domain account, created when the PDC was migrated from stand alone) account is installed in the Documents and Settings folder and profile list?

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

A) When becoming a PDC the local admin convert itself to the domain admin, no other account is created. (You can test it easily on a test server)

B) I didn't check but I'm pretty sure that the server will create a new admin profile the first time you log in with the domain administrator account. The local administrator will not change

Comment: For A) yes that is what happened.

Comment: For B)   (the BDC), another 'Administrator' account (a domain account) was created and the original local 'Administrator' account has now become an "unknown account".

Comment: I suspected that something had gone wrong and the local 'Administrator' account on the stand alone server (prior to it becoming the BDC) had been corrupted.  So if you are saying that it's normal for windows to create a new admin profile (domain 'Administrator' account), then I can be sure that there hasn't been any issue with it being added to the domain.

Comment: However, now that I know there hasn't been any issue, would it be possible to merge the newly created domain 'Administrator' account into the existing local 'Administrator' account on the BDC machine?

Comment: Also, what - if anything - should I do with the local 'Administrator' profile in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator  ?   Should it be deleted?  Would it still be necessary if the server would ever be removed from the domain?

Comment: yeya is correct.  Windows Domain Controllers do not have local accounts.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, unless you're running NT Server, there are no more PDCs/BDCs.  The only "PDC" left in a Windows domain is the PDC Emulator role.  It's most notable function is keeping time synchronized.

Comment: Please mark as 'answered' if you think you got your answer.